# How to get sonar to read code coverage reports that are in HTML format?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, code-coverage, sonarqube

I've been trying for the past two days to get my javascript code in my ruby application unit tested and reported on.
I've finally been able to run my javascript test against a headless browser using Jasmine and JCov (https://github.com/yp-engineering/jcov)
JCov can generate a report.html file, here is an example one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>JCov</title>
    </meta>
    <link href="report.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1>JCov : <span class="total-coverage"> 90%<span/></h1>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Filename</th><th>Coverage</th><th>Percent</th></tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascripts/mean.js.html">javascripts/mean.js</a></td>
        <td>(10/11)</td>
        <td> 90%</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><em>Total:</em></td>
        <td>(10/11)</td>
        <td> 90%</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, how can I get Sonar to read in this report? I've tried some relevant Google searches but most of the results lead to using JsTestDriver and using the LCOV file it
generates to give to Sonar using a sonar javascript plugin. The problem with that is JsTestDriver does not run against a headless brower natively and it
requires java, while JCov is a ruby Gem.

Answer (score 1):

I do confirm that the Sonar Javascript plugin only supports the import of JsTestDriver reports.